# Can not parse json file in go

Tags: json, go

I'm trying to parse a json file using GoLang but it seems like not work. Am I doing right?

this is  my Go Code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
)

type info struct {
    username   string   `json:"username"`
    password   string   `json:"password"`
    timedelay  int      `json:"timedelay"`
    courselist []string `json:"courselist"`
}

func main() {
    var jsonParse info
    file, err := ioutil.ReadFile("info.json")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("My file content is:\n", string(file))
    fmt.Println("---------------Parsing Json File----------------")

    json.Unmarshal(file, &jsonParse)
    fmt.Println("My Json Parse is:\n", jsonParse)

}
```

and this is my json file

```
{
    "username" : "17020726",
    "password": "Blueflower",
    "timedelay": 200,
    "courselist": ["54"]
}
```

this is result of my code

```
My file content is:
 {
    "username" : "17020726",
    "password": "Blueflower",
    "timedelay": 200,
    "courselist": ["54"]
}
---------------Parsing Json File----------------
My Json Parse is:
 {  0 []}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The info struct fields are private. Capitalize the first letters.